# Add buttons into List when mouse is HoldDown?

Tags: unity, gui

I have three buttons in my menu. What I need to do is when I click on first button it becomes the first element in my list. Now, when I keep mouse button down and move it to the second button it becomes the second second element in my list. The same with the third button.

```
public List<GameObject> UI_Button_List = new List<GameObject>(3);


void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {

    if (UI_Button_List[0] == null)
    {
        UI_Button_List[0] = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.gameObject;
    }
         
    if (UI_Button_List[0] != null && UI_Button_List[1] == null)
    {
        UI_Button_List[1] = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.gameObject;
    }

    if (UI_Button_List[0] != null && UI_Button_List[1] != null && UI_Button_List[2] == null)
    {
        UI_Button_List[2] = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.gameObject;
    }

    } // end if   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you can simplify what (I think) you are trying to achieve

```
public List<GameObject> UI_Button_List = new List<GameObject>(3);


void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        GameObject targetObject = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.gameObject;
        if (targetObject != null && !UI_Button_List.Contains(targetObject)
        {
            UI_Button_List.Add(targetObject);
        }

    } // end if   
}
```

Every frame if the mouse button is pressed down, we check the target object isn't null and that it isn't already added to the list, if it meets both conditions we add it to the list.

*.Add* will automatically increment the list index when successfully adding an element, so there's no need to check if there's anything already there, We already did the checks to make sure its a valid object and not already in the list with *!UI_Button_List.Contains(targetObject)*

If holding the mouse button in and 'dragging' down the UI_Buttons you want to click is what you are trying to achieve(which now I read it properly, it probably is) you can change the Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) to Input.GetMouseButton(0) which will fire every frame the button is held.

```
public List<GameObject> UI_Button_List = new List<GameObject>(3);

GameObject lastObject = null;
void Update()
{
    //Each frame the mouse is down
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        //Get object for current event
        GameObject targetObject = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.gameObject;

        if (targetObject == lastObject)
        {
            //return this frame if this object has either been added or rejected
            return;
        }

        if (targetObject != null && !UI_Button_List.Contains(targetObject))
        {
            UI_Button_List.Add(targetObject);
        }
        lastObject = targetObject;

    } // end if   

}
```

All I have added outside of the mouse event change is a check to make sure we're not dealing with an object same as last frame, no need to, but you can remove it without any trouble.

Edit:
It is quite difficult without knowing how everything fits together how you want a particular piece of code to function, and I am not on my own PC to fire up unity but I think the below (untested) should set you on the right path, you can also use the https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html UI Events Interface to make your UI Objects react to mouse events.

```
public List<GameObject> UI_Button_List = new List<GameObject>();

GameObject targetObject = null;
GameObject lastObject = null;

void Update()
{
    //Each frame the mouse is down
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        //Fire a ray from the Camera to the mouse position, using this function that converts from Screen Space (0,1) to World Space (x,y,z)
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, Mathf.Infinity, LayerMask.GetMask("UI")))
        {
            //If we are here, we hit a valid object
            targetObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
            //same check as before, make sure it isnt null now (for whatever reason not likely but still) and that our list doesnt already contain it
            if (targetObject != null && !UI_Button_List.Contains(targetObject))
            {
                UI_Button_List.Add(targetObject);
            }
        }

        lastObject = targetObject;

    } // end if   
}
```

Make sure your UI elements are on the UI Layer, or change the LayerMask.GetMask("UI") to whatever layer your UI is on.

Hopefully this is closer to what you want.

Comment: Did you mean to use Input.GetButton? GetButtonDown returns true only on a frame where the button transitioned from up to down, not on frames where it's been held down continuously.

Comment: Honestly not sure what exactly they are going for outside of adding something valid to a list, but it seems like they want 1 item to be added to the list per click? Hopefully OP can clear it up!

Comment: "when I keep mouse button down and move it" sounds to me like a click-and-drag, not a second click. But I agree, clarification from OP would be best.

Comment: Alrighty, yep that's totally on me! Reading comprehension lacking.

Comment: Thank you for trying helping me. //-DMGregory, Yes, you right. I need to add a button to my list when I keep pressing on muse button. When I press on first button, it goes to the first element in my list. Now, I'm still pressing on muse mutton, I move to the second button. When the pointer touch it, it should become the second element in my list. Like that. I read that only RayCast could do this. //-Phennix2105, Thank you man for your work. Your script is running fine, but it doesn't do what I need. I appreciate what you did for me.

Comment: Ah ha, I assumed you had already taken care of this because you are using the UI events! That should not be a big change, I will update the answer.